# Update to Xcode 9 makes fonts blurry

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I've recently updated my iOS app project for Xcode 9 and iPhone X and have a very strange problem.

The app, which looked good when built with Xcode 8.3.3, now looks all blurry. Fonts are not longer crisp.

The app is iPhone only and the target platform for the app is iOS 9.

I've noticed that the only device the app still looks good on is the "iPhone mode" (little sreen in the middle) of an iPad Air.

It seems as if some weird scaling effect is happening in the background but I can't figure out what it is.

I've tried setting the frames of labels with `CGRectIntegral()` method, to insure OK coordinates, but it did not change.

[image]

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of the screen?

Comment: I've attached the screenshot, so please take a look

Answer (score 1):

If you are noticing this behavior in the simulator, it's likely that you enabled **Physical Size** scaling. Go to **Window** and select **Pixel Accurate** to disable this function.

[image: Window/Pixel Accurate]

Comment: It happens on devices, so this doesn't help :(